# Why run method defined with abstract keyword in runnable interface

Tags: java

This question may be silly but i accidentally checked in java source code that run method in runnable interface is defined with abstract keyword.
But according to interface definition all methods in an interface are by default abstract.
Then i am confused why specially Runnable interface has  abstract keyword for run method.
I check with other interfaces like map , list etc but no one has abstract keyword.

Please give me an idea why it is written like this in java source code.

```
public abstract void run();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [java language specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#9.4):

> Every method declaration in the body
>   of an interface is implicitly
>   abstract, so its body is always
>   represented by a semicolon, not a
>   block.
>
> Every method declaration in the body
>   of an interface is implicitly public.
>
> For compatibility with older versions
>   of the Java platform, it is permitted
>   but discouraged, as a matter of style,
>   to redundantly specify the abstract
>   modifier for methods declared in
>   interfaces.
>
> It is permitted, but strongly
>   discouraged as a matter of style, to
>   redundantly specify the public
>   modifier for interface methods.

Hey, just learned that my interface declarations are bad style, because I always use the `public` modifier.

---

[apache Harmony](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Runnable.java.html) just adds the public modifier (*uuuh - bad style!*). <strike>SUN</strike>Oracle has both modifiers? I guess that's because in the 'older versions' it was mandatory to add the `abstract` modifier - just because the JLS mentions 'compatibilty with older versions'.

And then: *Never change a Runnable system* :-)

Comment: This still doesn't answer *why* the Sun guys putted `public abstract` specifically in the `run()` method. That's what his whole question was about.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the preferred coding style. My interface declarations have also been bad style until now ;)

Comment: @BalusC perhaps that particular declaration was never refactored when the convention changed? Since there's apparently no technical reason, will we ever know?

Comment: @chris: mdma has already answered it. It's a leftover from dark 1.0 ages.

Answer (score 14):

The 'public' declaration is also redundant, since all symbols are public by default in an interface.

It's probably written like this just out of habit. I imagine that `Runnable` was amongst the first handful of interfaces conceived in JDK 1.0, and that that time, the declaration defaults for interfaces had probably not been fully instilled in the minds of the JDK developers. I remember reading in an interview with James Gosling, that in Oak, the project name for what became Java, there were once no interfaces, just abstract classes like C++, and this may be a hangover from that.

I also sometimes write "public" for interface methods and constants, although it's not necessary.

Comment: Ya i know that and i want to know why java code of runnable interface is written like this because it does not require any public and abstract keyword i have checked other interfaces given by java foundation but all are normal only this interface has this confusing definition i have not got anything on any java forum why runnable was written like this

Comment: I explain in my answer why I think it is written like this. It's most likely a throwback from when there were no interfaces, just abstract classes. It does no real harm, so noone has bothered to remove it, since that might do more harm than good (although right now, difficult to see what harm that might be.)

Comment: @Willi - a programming language is usually unambiguous, and doesn't "kind of" work in one way or another. For interfaces, the JLS states all interface members are implicitly public. See JLS, 9.1.5: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#17145

Answer (score 1):

All methods in an interface are public and abstract, but you are not actually required to specify that using keywords. It will be done automatically for you. You could just have `void run()` and it would mean the same thing.

Comment: Ya i know that and i want to know why java code of runnable interface is written like this because it does not require any public and abstract keyword .

Comment: He didn't ask that. He asked why it's appearing in java source code with `public abstract` while in other interfaces they are (correctly) left away.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's been written like this in the Java source code is because it has been overlooked by the author.

The definition:

```
public abstract void run();
```

is exactly the same as the definition:

```
public void run();
```

in an interface. It is simply a matter of style. It is the preferred style in Java interfaces that interface methods be defined without the public and abstract keywords.

Note that there is no difference in functionality between these two method definitions in an interface.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a pretty pointless question. At least it's a pointless place to ask it. You would need to ask the author. To which he would probably reply 'who cares?'

Comment: It's interesting. That's all.